# Unable to delete Team Foundation Service project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, project, azure-devops

I'm using Visual Studio Pro 2012, with Team Foundation Service. I have several projects on the server I want to delete. I'm trying to use Developer Command Prompt for VS2012 to delete a project on the server with the command:

```
TfsDeleteProject /q /force /collection:https://<your tenant 
name>.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection <Project Name>
```

However I get the response:

```
TF200040: You cannot delete a team project with your version of Team Explorer. C
ontact your system administrator to determine how to upgrade your Team Explorer
client to the version compatible with Team Foundation Server.
```

I have installed Team Explorer 2012 and this has made no difference.
How can I delete a project or resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, we broke it in a deployment this week. We deployed the fix today. Sorry for the trouble!

Answer (score 2):

Needs to be in this path:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE

Also make sure you don't put quotes round the project name (seems to break it):
TfsDeleteProject /q /force collection:https://myproj.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection MyProject